# how to handle unique links in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a performance test for customer application where they can see their invoices.

I am using CSV config file for picking username and password of 1000 users.

after logging in i want to click on Invoice **view** button but every invoice link is unique so my script is being failed.

please Help

link example:  ------url-----\unique Invoice number\view

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract path to "View" page after logging in into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and use it as a parameter in the relevant request. The most commonly used test element for it is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). Something like:

- Log In

  - Regular Expression Extractor -> Get "View" page URL
- Open "View" page using URL from the Regular Expression Extractor

See:

- [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter - Part 1: Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) - for more detailed explanation with examples
- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) JMeter User Manual chapter - for general information on regular expressions
- [Perl5 Regex Cheat Sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet) - regex syntax explained